# voice search in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i am developing a windows phone 7 application.

I want to have a search textbox where it search some data when the search keyword is given.

i want to implement voice search like bing have.

Anyone have idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no library for speech recognition on WP7 but you can use speech recognition through a service.

You can find here an example on how to use speech recognition on Windows Phone 7 through a service:

[Windows Phone 7 Prototype 001: Speech Recognition on WP7](https://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/05/windows-phone-7-prototype-001-speech-recognition-on-wp7/)

Comment: Links are unavailable, so this comment is useless. That's why you should include code snippets in comments.

Answer (score 1):

There's no public API available for this **yet**. You can register at [Microsoft Tellme](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Tellme/developers/default.aspx) to get information on when it's done.

Also take a look at [Microsoft Project Hawaii](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hawaii/students/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Has there been any updates on Tellme's API? Their website is quite vague. I see SAPI, but there's not mention of using it for Windows Phone.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Tellme/developers/default.aspx?tab=desktop